# Read a list of dynamic objects into CSV

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, reflection

I'm attempting to read a big list of data into a flat CSV. One field of each row is XML data - with the XML dictating additional Properties in each row. Therefore each row could have slightly different Properties.

I've got my list in an initial structured class:

```
private class Response {
    public Response() {
        Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; } // XML data in here
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I then thought to make my list dynamic to handle the varied Properties:

```
var responses = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var response in query) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Data))
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(response.Data);

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("field")) {
        try
        {
            response.Values.Add(node.FirstChild.InnerText, node.LastChild.InnerText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // log
        }
    }
}

            dynamic fullResponse = new ExpandoObject();
            fullResponse.Owner = response.Owner;
            fullResponse.Author = response.Author;
            fullResponse.Email = response.Email;
            fullResponse.Created = response.Created;

            IDictionary<string, object> map = fullResponse;
            foreach (var value in response.Values) {
                if (map.ContainsKey(value.Key)) {
                    map[value.Key] = value.Value;
                }
                else {
                    map.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
                }
            }

            responses.Add(fullResponse);
        }
```

... which also works fine. But now I want to basically flatten this list and export it as a CSV, knowing that each row of my dynamic list might have slightly different properties.

Grabbing the `PropertyInfo`, a dynamic type, obviously comes back with nothing. Am I just going to have to loop through my list to extract the unique properties manually into something like a DataTable? Or are there some calls I can make with Reflection to get this done more efficiently?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `responses` with two different entries and how you would like your csv to look like? You already have KeValuePairs of properties and values in your `ExpandoObject fullResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a plain old DataTable to get it sorted:

```
using (var dt = new DataTable())
{
     var keys = responses.SelectMany(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x).Keys).Distinct();
     var columns = keys.Select(x => new DataColumn(x)).ToArray();
     dt.Columns.AddRange(columns);

     foreach(IDictionary<string, object> response in responses)
     {
         var row = dt.NewRow();
         foreach (var kvp in response)
         {
             row[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
         }
         dt.Rows.Add(row);
     }

     // write to CSV
}
```

Though I feel like I could've done something a lot cooler with Reflection to achieve the same result.